# Is there a way to open windows terminal shells in the current directory with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-explorer, windows-terminal

I've Windows Terminal (Preview) pinned to **taskbar** which I launch using `win+t`. I'm trying to achieve a similar functionality to `alt+f+r` inside a directory in file explorer which opens `powershell` in the current directory. I've tried setting `startDirectory` in `profiles.json` to `null`, `"."` and "~" but none work.

I think it's not possible for the terminal to know which directory I'm currently in if I launch it from the taskbar, if so, is there a way to launch it through file explorer (preferably using keyboard shortcuts only) and have the terminal shells open in the current directory?

Comment: When in Explorer you type in the address bar `wt.exe` and Enter, does it launch Windows Terminal inside the current folder?

Comment: @harrymc yes it does, but only when `startingDirectory` is set to `"."`, is there a shortcut for this? don't want to type in wt.exe. Perhaps any registry tweaks?

Comment: I'm not using Windows Terminal, but my answer should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the free key-remapping product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Here is a script that will start the Windows Terminal on the current folder
in Explorer when <kbd>F12</kbd> is clicked.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
~F12::
    ControlGetText, _Path, toolbarwindow322, ahk_class CabinetWClass
    StringReplace, _Path, _Path,% "Address: ",% ""
    Run "wt.exe", %_Path%
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

For choosing another hotkey than <kbd>F12</kbd>, see AutoHotkey
[List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

---

You could also add this to the shell context menu by
[this method](https://lifehacker.com/add-any-application-to-the-windows-context-menu-1627589106):

1. Start `regedit` and navigate to the key
   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`
2. Right-click `shell` and select `New > Key`, naming it perhaps
   `Windows Terminal`
3. Right-click the new `Windows Terminal` key and select again `New > Key`,
   naming it `command`
4. In the new `command` key folder, double-click the `(Default)` key
   on the right and set it to the path to the executable file and hit OK.

You will probably not be able to set the command to
`\path\wt.exe "%V"`, because Windows Terminal does not accept parameters,
so you will need to use a batch file, `\path\script.bat "%V"`,
where the batch file will look like:

```
cd "%1"
start "" \path\wt.exe
```

Comment: That's great and all, and I already knew about AHK but I'm looking for an answer that doesn't require third party tools.

Comment: Is that a reason for the downvote? You didn't state that in your post. The only other way is to do it yourself by typing "Ctrl+L wt Enter".

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted. Don't have enough rep yet for downvote. You're correct I didn't mention that explicitly but I was really lookin for, perhaps, even a registry tweak to add `wt.exe` in the right click menu.

Comment: Some downvotes are incomprehensible. I added a second method using the registry that you will need to try, since I don't have Windows Terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I should mention, you do not need a `.bat` file, just put `\path\to\wt.exe` in `command` and put `"."` in `startingDirectory` in `profiles.json` of the terminal.

Comment: Glad it helped. In order not to leave the post as `-1`, it would be more appropriate to upvote it (the up-arrow sign).

Answer (score 0):

You can add PowerShell to the Quick Access toolbar, and use e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>. The number depends on the location of the command on that toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** This answer will enable you to use **Shift+Context Menu Key, t** (or Shift+F10, t) on either the folder background, a selected file, or a selected folder, and it will open Windows Terminal in the path to the open folder, the path to the selected file, or the path to the selected folder. It also has options for opening an elevated version.

Below is a link to an article about adding "Open Windows Terminal Command Prompt" to the context menu in Explorer, which includes a shortcut to the elevated version and also keyboard shortcuts that can be accessed using Shift+Context Menu Key (or Shift+F10 if you don't have a context menu key).

**NOTE:** If there is more than one menu item assigned to 't', then you will have to press 't' until the option you want is selected, and then press Enter. You can also change 't' to whatever you want by moving the & in the menu text or even add characters to the string to make it unique so you can avoid having to press Enter.

https://dkcool.tailnet.net/2020/07/add-open-windows-terminal-command-prompt-to-the-explorer-context-menu-in-windows-10/

If you want it to open powershell and not the command prompt, then you can modify the registry values in the article and change "Command Prompt" in the command key default value to "Windows Powershell". If you want it to open an Ubuntu shell, change "Command Prompt" to the specific name that you have installed, like "Ubuntu-18.04". See the Microsoft link below for more command line options.

WT.exe command line arguments: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows

Similar article about adding Open Admin Command Prompt to the context menu in Explorer: https://dkcool.tailnet.net/2019/05/add-open-admin-command-prompt-to-the-explorer-context-menu-in-windows-10/